# execvp command not running ls -l *.c

Tags: c, unix, system, system-calls, systems-programming

My `execvp` is not running `ls -l *.c` command. I have tried to use two methods :

1. One with the file path where my ls is located which is in `\bin\ls`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *cmdargs[] = { "ls", "-l", "*.c", NULL };
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        execvp("\bin\ls", cmdargs);
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child terminates\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
ls: *.c: No such file or directory
Child terminates
```

2. The second method I used was to add `cmdargs[0]` instead of the file path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *cmdargs[] = { "ls", "-l", "*.c", NULL };
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        execvp(cmdargs[0], cmdargs);
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child terminates\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ls: *.c: No such file or directory
Child terminates
```

When I just run the command `ls -l *.c`, it does show me all the files which end with `.c`. Execvp does not show me the files. There was a question related to this but that did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

GLOB pattern is expanded by shell, not the `ls` itself.
You may achieve what you want by creating a subshell via exec.
Here's an example of that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    char *cmdargs[] = { "sh", "-c", "ls -l *.c", NULL };

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        execvp(cmdargs[0], cmdargs);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child terminates\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You may also employ `system(3)` for this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk pattern `*` is carried on by the shell, but by the `ls`.

You can use `exec` with `sh`, for example.

Editing over the OP’s response,
Obtain all files without using `*.c`in a string array and filter the strings as you wish.

Comment: This is my homework question and it asks me to use execvp only.

Comment: @VipulSharma there's no system call `exec`, `exec` is a name of family of system calls
`execl, execlp, execle, execv, execvp, execvpe - execute a file` from `man 3 exec`.

So technically there's no contradiction :)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `ls -l *.c`, the shell will parse that command, find the glob pattern and expand it. It will then call `ls` with the expanded argument list, calling `execvp` with an array like `{"ls", "-l", "a.c", "b.c", "c.c", NULL}`. Neither `ls` nor the `execvp` expand globs by themselves, it's the shell that does it.

So if you want to use globs, your options are to either expand them yourself (either by manually going through the current directory and adding all files that end with `.c` to your array or by using the POSIX glob function), or to go through the shell. You can do the latter either by explicitly invoking by using `{"sh", "-c", "ls -l *.c", NULL}` as the array you pass to `execvp` (or similarly, but without the array, using `execl` etc.) or you could use `system("ls -l *.c")`, which always goes through the shell.

Note that you definitely don't want to go through the shell if the arguments contain untrusted user input, so in that case expanding the glob(s) yourself / using `glob` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to invoking the shell to expand the `*.c` glob pattern to files, you can use [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) to expand `*.c` to list of files yourself and then construct a dynamically allocated array of arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    glob_t result = {0};
    int err = glob("*.c", GLOB_ERR, NULL, &result);
    if (err) return err;
    char **cmdargs = malloc((2 + result.gl_pathc + 1) * sizeof(cmdargs));
    if (cmdargs == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    cmdargs[0] = "ls";
    cmdargs[1] = "-l";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.gl_pathc; ++i) {
        cmdargs[i + 2] = result.gl_pathv[i];
    }
    cmdargs[2 + result.gl_pathc] = NULL;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        execvp(cmdargs[0], cmdargs);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child terminates\n");
    }
    globfree(&result);
    return 0;
}
```